# Can you set Finder to show the file extension in the Kind column rather than a description?

Tags: macos, finder, mojave

In Finder (Mojave if it's relevant), the 'Kind' column displays the file format in a 'friendly' human-readable format like "JPEG Image". Things like Photoshop and Illustrator files have descriptions like "Adobe Photoshop document". This is a problem - on a 13" screen, the Kind column is narrow enough that what you actually get is "Adobe...cument". This makes finding filetypes at a glance annoying.

Is there a way to have it simply use the file extension - PSD, AI, JPEG - instead of the full text description? Yes, I already have extensions displayed on the filenames themselves.

Comment: No. But if you already have the extensions showing, then you don't really need a separate column, do you?